# How to call a child method from the parent in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When a click event is fired within my parent component I need to call the method closeMenu() from the SearchBar child component.  I have tried a couple of different ways to do that but none of them are working.  Does anyone know how to do this?

```
class Products extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { closeMenu: false};

    this.hideSearchBar = this.hideSearchBar.bind(this);
}

hideSearchBar(e) {
    console.log('e: ', React.Children)
    this.setState({closeMenu: true});
    this.refs.SearchBar.closeMenu();
    this.setState({closeMenu: false});        
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(getProductList());
}

render() {
    const {isLoading, products} = this.props.products;

    if (isLoading) {
        return <Loader isVisible={true}/>;
    }

    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={(e) => this.hideSearchBar(e)} style={{zIndex: 0}}>
            <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                <Header/>
                <View style={styles.bodyWrapper}>
                    <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
                        <ProductsContainer data={{productsList: { results: products }}}/>
                    </ScrollView>
                    <SearchBar ref="SearchBar" style={styles.searchBar} />
                </View>
                <Footer/>
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}
```

}

I also tried calling closeMenu() without refs:

```
hideSearchBar(e) {
    this.setState({closeMenu: true});
    this.SearchBar.closeMenu();
}
```

Here is the SearchBar component:

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.suggestions = [];
}

componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log("COMPONENT WILL UPDATE");
    console.log(nextProps);
    console.log(nextState);
}

suggestionClick = (value) => {

}

getSuggestionText = (suggestion) => {

}

onChangeText = (value) => {
    this.selectedSuggestion = false
    this.props.dispatch(handleSearchItemText(value));
    console.log(this.props.products.searchResults);
}

onFocus() {
    const {height} = Dimensions.get('window');
    this.setState({
        contentOffset: {
            x: 0,
            y: height * 1 / 3
        }
    });
}

onBlur() {
    this.setState({
        contentOffset: {x: 0, y: 0}
    });
}

closeMenu = () => {
    this.props.products.searchResults = {};
}

componentWillReceiveProps() {
    if (!this.props.closeMenu) {
        this.props.closeMenu = false;
    }
}

renderSearches = () => {
    this.suggestions = this.props.products.searchResults;
    const suggestionTexts = Object.keys(this.props.products.searchResults || {})

    console.log(suggestionTexts);
    if (!suggestionTexts.length) {
        return null
    }
    // for android absolute element: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16951
    // https://gist.github.com/tioback/6af21db0685cd3b1de28b84981f31cca#file-input-with-suggestions-L54
    return (
        <View
            ref="suggestionsWrapper"
            style={autoStyles.suggestionsWrapper}
        >
            {
                this.suggestions.map((text, index) => (
                    <TouchableHighlight
                        key={index}
                        suggestionText={text}
                        activeOpacity={0.6}
                        style={autoStyles.suggestion}
                        onPress={this.suggestionClick(this.suggestions[text])}
                        underlayColor='white'
                    >
                        <Text style={autoStyles.suggestionText}>
                            {text}
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                ))
            }
        </View>
    )
}

render() {
    const myIcon = (<Icon name="search" size={30} style={styles.searchIcon}/>);
    const slidersIcon = (<Icon name="sliders" size={30} style={styles.slidersIcon}/>);

    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={{zIndex: 0}}>
            <View style={[styles.searchBar, this.props.style]}>
                <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
                    <View>
                        {slidersIcon}
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.search}>
                        <View style={styles.searchSection}>
                            {myIcon}
                            <TextInput
                                style={styles.input}
                                placeholder="Search"
                                placeholderTextColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"
                                onChangeText={(searchString) => {
                                    this.setState({searchString})
                                }}
                                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                                editable={true}
                                autoCorrect={false}
                                autoFocus={false}
                                autoCaptialize={'none'}
                                autoCorrect={false}
                                onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
                                enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
                                onFocus={() => this.onFocus()}
                                onBlur={() => this.onBlur()}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
                {this.renderSearches()}
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Not doing this is a core principle of react. The correct way to do this is to call `setState()` in the parent which triggers a re-render of its children passing new props to it. Your child can then render accordingly. Create a state property `isMenuOpen` and pass that to the `SearchBar` component. It can then call close when `isMenuOpen` changes to `false`. I will provide a more detailed example shortly.

Comment: Could you please add the complete code of `SearchBar`?

Comment: I tried doing that at first then discovered I would have to find a way to pass props again back to my parent when the child method is done.  Because I set closeMenu to true in hideSearchBar it only works the first time because after that it no longer triggers a re-render.  So I need to be able to change it back to false every time and I cannot do that in the child component method because I don't know how to pass props back to the parent to update closeMenu variable.

Comment: I will post the complete code now.  Hold on let me update my question.

Comment: I wait for your example.

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues which you should avoid:

**Never mutate props**: `this.props.something = {}` is an anti-pattern. Think about props as data that your component does not own and which are not mutable. If they change then only because the parent passed new props.

Also you have multiple handlers in your `SeachBar` that are not bound to `this` but use `this`. It will not work. Use arrow functions if you want to use `this` or bind them in the `constructor`.

You should overthink the architecture of your app. Maybe it is a good idea to split the search bar and the result list into two separate components. When the user types something to search for update your redux store and display the results in a separate component that you only render if there are search results.

I'm affraid it would exceed the length of a stackoverflow answer to solve all these issues. Maybe you should go back to the basics first and do the really good redux tutorial.

Comment: I do not need all of these issues resolved right now.  I did not write all of this code myself.  This is an app where multiple people write code.  So many of the things that you point out I didn't actually do.  They will get fixed later.  I just need to know how to call a child method from the parent OR how the child can update props in the parent.

Comment: @Tanya look, most of us here also work as developers, we get it that sometimes you need a quick fix for various real-life reasons. But this is a *design smell*, you are almost certainly creating extra work (and extra bugs) by trying to hammer a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: @Tanya Okay to make it very clear: **You can't call functions on children**. If you feel that you need to do it you are doing it wrong. Also you can't "update props". You get them from outside. If you want to signalize to your parent that something should change you should call a handler that you got from the parent via props. The parent can then act accordingly (e.g. by changing its state and passing new props on re-render that reflect the changes). Stackoverflow is not a coding service. I gave you the right hints. Whoever wrote that code, it needs a rewrite.